# Queries that ran, and the number of times they ran

Tags: mysql-5.5, hibernate

I want to profile a running web application in dev on a mysql 5.5 database.  The web application uses hibernate and I am able to see that a rather large number of queries are run against the database.

I'm able to see long running queries with logging, but that is not a concern as they are all running fairly quickly.

What I would like to know is, what queries are being run, and how many times they are run.

Comment: Daniel, I've just rejected your edit, not because I think it is harmful but because it changes Ahmad's suggestion significantly.  It is OK to post an answer to your own question, and even to accept it as *the* answer if you choose.

Comment: I did the same. Your content seems reasonable, but really should be a separate answer. It's perfectly ok to answer your own question.

Comment: I disagree, I simply added documentation for commands he used.  His answer is correct, but I wanted more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the query monitoring you have two solutions from MySQL level:

solution 1:

create log file for the query by editing `my.ini` or `my.cnf`

```
slow_query_log_file = "C:/slowquery.log"
log = log_file_name
```

solution 2:

Create log tables:

Slow queries:

```
CREATE TABLE `slow_log` (
   `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                          ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
   `query_time` time NOT NULL,
   `lock_time` time NOT NULL,
   `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
   `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL,
   `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log'
```

General queries

```
CREATE TABLE `general_log` (
   `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                          ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
   `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log'


  SET global general_log = 1;
SET global log_output = 'table';
```

To show the log use the following command:

select * from mysql.general_log;

if you want the slow query:

```
select * from mysql.slow_log;
```

To count the number of query executing:

```
show session status like "Queries";
```

Comment: References from the mysql 5.5 docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/log-destinations.html

Comment: Also, because comments are short, here is more detail inpired by Ahmad's answer: https://bowerstudios.com/node/1235